# Is there a way to order rows based on custom rules in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Below is my sample table:

```
 id  nv  ov        date
  1   1   0  01/02/2023
  1   2   1  01/02/2023
  1   5   4  01/03/2023
  1   1   3  01/02/2023
  1   4   1  01/02/2023
  1   3   2  01/02/2023
  1   6   5  01/03/2023
  1   7   6  01/04/2023
  1   7   7  01/04/2023
```

where `nv` is new value and `ov` is old value.

I want to order all the rows according to the correct change log between new values and old values i.e. new value of previous row should match with old value of current row.

Also, if there are multiple cases where new value is matching with old value, only correct case should be taken forward. For example, after (1,0), I can either go to (2,1) or (4,1); but (2,1) is the correct log since it will cover all transitions. If (4,1) is chosen at this point as row number 3, then all change log will not be covered. The row where old value is null will always be the first row.

*(PS: I do have a date column but there are multiple transitions happening on the same date. In that case, how to determine the correct order of these transitions for the mentioned use-case? i.e. Transition from 1 to 2 and 1 to 4 is happening on the same day.)*

Can we do this in [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas)/[python](/questions/tagged/python)?

Expected Output:

```
 id  nv  ov       date  rn
  1   1   0 01/02/2023   1
  1   2   1 01/02/2023   2
  1   3   2 01/02/2023   3
  1   1   3 01/02/2023   4
  1   4   1 01/02/2023   5
  1   5   4 01/03/2023   6
  1   6   5 01/03/2023   7
  1   7   6 01/04/2023   8
  1   7   7 01/04/2023   9
```

Comment: Can you have more than one cycle? In this case what is the rule?

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)?

Comment: Normal sort wouldn't work here since I can go back to a previous state also.

Comment: ideally no, we won't have more than one cycle; but yeah I understand programmatically it might be difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, quite an interesting problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can tackle this problem using a graph approach with help of [`networkx`](https://networkx.org).

Here is your graph:

[image: graph of dataframe columns]

Here we will identify the root and leaf (I assumed they are unique) and compute the simple path that excluded the cycles with [`all_simple_edge_paths`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_edge_paths.html). Then we identify all cycles with [`simple-cycles`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles.html#simple-cycles) and iterate their edges with [`dfs_edges`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search.dfs_edges.html#dfs-edges)  to add a sub-sorting key (here as a decimal part to the sorting key)

This will yield the following "order" for each edge, which we will then use for sorting:

[image]

Code of the `sorter` function that will add an "order" column (pre-requisite: no duplicated edges and only one root and leaf, although the code can be updated to handle more cases):

```
import networkx as nx

def sorter(df):
    # get root and leafs
    root = df.loc[~df['ov'].isin(df['nv']), 'ov'].squeeze()
    leaf = df.loc[df['ov'].eq(df['nv']), 'ov'].squeeze()

    # build graph
    G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='ov', target='nv',
                                create_using=nx.DiGraph)

    # find order of the edges from root to leafs, excluding cycles
    order = {e: i for i, e in enumerate(next(nx.all_simple_edge_paths(G, root, leaf)), start=1)}
    # get nodes that are in this normal path
    nodes = {n for k in order for n in k}

    # compute a step that will be used to add decimals for subsorting
    # this depends on the number of initial rows
    step = 10**-np.ceil(np.log10(df.shape[0]+1))
    # for each cycle
    for c in nx.simple_cycles(G):
        # get subgraph
        common = nodes & set(c)
        G2 = G.subgraph(c)
        for n in common:
            parent_edge = (next(G.predecessors(n)), n)
            edge = None
            # enumerate edges of the cycle in order and
            # add a sorting index from the parent edge + step
            for i, edge in enumerate(nx.dfs_edges(G2, source=n), start=1):
                order[edge] = order[parent_edge] + step * i
            if edge:
                order[(edge[1], n)] = order[parent_edge] + step * (i+1)
            else:
                order[(n, n)] = order[parent_edge] + step

    # build a sorting Series
    s = pd.Series(order).rename_axis(['ov', 'nv']).reset_index(name='order')
    
    # merge the order to original data and return
    return df.merge(s, on=['nv', 'ov'], how='left')
```

Then run:

```
out = sorter(df).sort_values(by=['date', 'order'])
```

If you want to sort per group, use the function within a [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
out = (df.groupby('id', group_keys=False).apply(sorter)
         .sort_values(by=['id', 'date', 'order'])
       )
```

Output:

```
   id  nv  ov        date  order
0   1   1   0  01/02/2023    1.0
1   1   2   1  01/02/2023    1.1
5   1   3   2  01/02/2023    1.2
3   1   1   3  01/02/2023    1.3
4   1   4   1  01/02/2023    2.0
2   1   5   4  01/03/2023    3.0
6   1   6   5  01/03/2023    4.0
7   1   7   6  01/04/2023    5.0
8   1   7   7  01/04/2023    5.1
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'nv': [1, 2, 5, 1, 4, 3, 6, 7, 7],
                   'ov': [0, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7],
                   'date': ['01/02/2023', '01/02/2023', '01/03/2023', '01/02/2023', '01/02/2023', '01/02/2023', '01/03/2023', '01/04/2023', '01/04/2023']})
```

Comment: NB. I forgot to mention the numpy import: `import numpy as np`, `math` can also be used (`10**-math.ceil(math.log10(10+1))`)

Comment: very very grateful Chief! Although, like you mentioned, I do have duplicated edges :(
For example: 
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'nv': [2, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7],
                   'ov': [1, 2, 7, 7, 6, 7],
                   'date': ['01/02/2023', '01/02/2023', '01/02/2023', '01/02/2023', '01/02/2023', '02/02/2023']})
Also, I am getting StopIteration error when I have only 2 transitions:
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1],
                   'nv': [2, 7,],
                   'ov': [1, 2],
                   'date': ['01/02/2023', '01/02/2023']})

Comment: Also, getting NodeNotFound error for the below input: df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1],'nv': [2, 1, 7],'ov': [1, 2, 1], 'date': ['01/02/2023', '01/02/2023', '02/02/2023']})... I guess that's because it got confused with root node being 1

Comment: The issue is the ambiguity of the leaf, what is it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOTX3.png) ? I considered in my code the root to be the the node absent from `nv` and the leaf the node that has a self edge. Please clarify the rules.

Comment: And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjMV2.png) where is the root? Both 1 and 2 could be

Comment: Yeah the graph is correct; but I understand now. It will be difficult to find the correct path when leaves are repeating. The expected output was: (1) 1-->2 (2) 2 --> 7 (3) 7 --> 7 (4) 7 --> 6 (5) 6 --> 7 (6) 7 --> 7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252034/discussion-between-midoriya007-and-mozway).

Comment: Yeah the graph is correct; but I understand now. The expected output was: (1) 1->2 (2) 2 -> 7 (3) 7 -> 7 (4) 7 -> 6 (5) 6 -> 7 (6) 7 -> 7
In the second case, 1 is the root. 1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 1 ->7 was the expected order.
It's not necessary for the leaf node to have a self edge. That was just one of the case.

Comment: Unfortunately, the root node can be present in nv. If the exact path is not possible, can we find all the paths?
A brief way to explain this problem which comes to my mind is: all the edges(including repeated edges to be considered separate) should be travelled exactly once first sorting on the date.